# Renaming directories inside the tar.gz while extracting the tar in linux

Tags: shell, unix

I have a tarball Index.tar.gz. Inside that I have directories like this

Index1/db_newtime_oldtime_0
Index1/db_newtime_oldtime_1
Index1/db_newtime_oldtime_2
Index2/db_newtime_oldtime_0
Index2/db_newtime_oldtime_1
Index2/db_newtime_oldtime_2

While extracting the tar file, I want to add 99 with the numeric value at the end of the db directory name. 
So after extraction the directory structure should be like this

Index1/db_newtime_oldtime_99
Index1/db_newtime_oldtime_100
Index1/db_newtime_oldtime_101
Index2/db_newtime_oldtime_99
Index2/db_newtime_oldtime_100
Index2/db_newtime_oldtime_101

So is it possible to rename like this by using shell script ?

Answer (score 0):

after extracting tar ball you can just rename each of the directory names inside `index*/`...
You can use a for loop to do that :

```
for i in $(\ls -d index*/*); 
do 
    dst=$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's/oldtime_/oldtime_ /g' | awk '{print $1$2+99}'); 
    mv "$i" "$dst"; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to test this. If not missed anything while tar-gzipping....

```
tar -C ./tmp -xvf ./Index.tar.gz
find ./tmp -name "[a-zA-Z_][0-9]" | sed s/([a-zA-Z])([0-9])/\1 \2 | awk '{print "mv "$1$2" "$1$2+99}'
cd ./tmp && tar -zxf ../Index.tar.gz . && cd ../ && rm -rf ./tmp
```

NOTE:
yes, AWK supports math :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash:

```
tar -vxf Index.tar.gz | (
    R='^(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)$'
    read A
    while [[ -n $A ]]; do
        read B
        [[ $A =~ $R ]] && echo mv "$A" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$(( BASH_REMATCH[2] + 99 ))"
        A=$B
    done
)
```

Note: The `-v` is important. Remove `echo` near `mv` if it seems to work well already.